# CakePHP Validate a specific rule only when a couple required fields aren't empty

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I wrote a custom rule method for validating whether a record exists in the DB before adding a new record.  I put the method in a behavior so I could share it with other models, but I've run into a chicken and egg situation.

In order to know whether a category has a specific group name already I need to have the category id, and the group name.  So I pass those keys through using my custom rule (category_id and name).  But, this won't work since if I don't choose a category_id by mistake then the query will occur on just the name, so I patched this with a couple lines, but need to return true if this is the case and bank on the category_id validation being invalid.

Is there a better way to implement this kind of validation? Is this not as bad as I think? Or just don't bother and in my controller drop hasAny() under my call to validates() if it passes.

```
MODEL:
public $validate = [
    'category_id' => [
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Category is required.'
    ],
    'name'      => [
        'notEmpty'     => [
            'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Team is required.'
        ],
        'recordExists' => [
            'rule'    => [ 'recordExists', [ 'category_id', 'name' ] ],
            'message' => 'Group already exists.'
        ]
    ]
];

// BEHAVIOR:
public function recordExists( Model $Model, $conditions, $requireKeys )
{
    // Overrite conditions to
    $conditions = $Model->data[ $Model->name ];

    // Trim all array elements and filter out any empty indexes
    $conditions = array_map( 'trim', $conditions );
    $conditions = array_filter( $conditions );

    // Get the remaining non-empty keys
    $conditionKeys = array_keys( $conditions );

    // Only query for record if all required keys are in conditions
    if (empty( array_diff( $requireKeys, $conditionKeys ) )) {
        return !$Model->hasAny( $conditions );
    }

    // NOTE: seems wrong to return true based on the assumption the category_id validation has probably failed
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [beforeValidate()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-Model.html#_beforeValidate) callback of the model to check if the fields are present and if they're empty. If they're empty just unset() the `recordExists` validation rule in your models validation property. Copy them to a temporary variable or property in the case you want to set them back after your current operation.

And use `$Model->alias`, `name` will break if the model is used through an association that has a different name.

```
$conditions = $Model->data[ $Model->name ];
```